# Static fiels doesn't load in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm using django1.11 to build a web app.I have add required settings for static files in settings.py and all of static files was working fine. But I was trying to add 404 custom templates during that suddenly my static files stop loading.

Here's my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'IGui', 'static'),
)
```

Here's my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', home_url.index, name='home'),
url(r'^dockers/', views.DockerStuff.as_view(), name='docker-stuff'),
url(r'^user/', include(user_urls, namespace='users')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My directory tree:

-IGui

- IGui
- -static
- --css
- --js

Help me, please!

Comment: Look in your web server log to see the path where the browser is trying to load them.  That should be a good first step in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Its load from " http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css "

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def handler404(request):
    response = render_to_response('404.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 404
    return response


def handler500(request):
    response = render_to_response('500.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response.status_code = 500
    return response
```

Add in you views.py the following two views, and just set up the templates 404.html and 500.html with what you want to display.

No custom code needs to be added to urls.py

Comment: Hi @Nicose! but to do this we need to set debug to False, when we do that again static files doesn't work.

Comment: When you go to production you will anyway set debug to False.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn Debug to True in settings.py will solve this issue.